# To connect a server in LAN with QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

We use windows10 as OS. I developed a very basic client/server app to chat. My PC act like a server. When I run 2 clients on my machine, they can connect to server and communicate.

But when I try to connect to server from another PC, client cannot connect.

My current "ipconfig" result from command line: IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.40. I can ping from another PC to this adress but in my exe client can not connect.

I use port 5050 in server app to be able to be connected.

I do not have expert knowledge in network programming so maybe it is about a firewall or something like that. I need help for them also.

My client code:

`m_socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
 m_socket->connectToHost("192.168.1.40", 5050);
 m_socket->waitForConnected(3000);`

My server code:

```
void ChatServer::buttonRun_triggered()
{
    if (!m_tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress::Any, m_defaultPort))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "Cannot listen socket");
        return;
    }
}

QObject::connect(&m_tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &ChatServer::newConnectionHandler);

void ChatServer::newConnectionHandler()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_mutex);

    QTcpSocket *socket = m_tcpServer.nextPendingConnection();
    ClientInfo *ci = new ClientInfo(socket, this);

    m_clients.push_back(ci);
}
```

The code, the ip adress names, ports all of them are the same for both client runs on my PC and client runs on another PC.

SOLVED: It was about firewall. After i had closed it, clients run without an error.

Comment: Please show server code

Comment: I've edited @Macias